# SQL : Splitting a column into multiple columns, by a common string separator where string has uneven length (TD14)

Tags: sql, formatting, teradata, split

I have an issue with splitting a variable I am recording, in which various values are separated with a `@` sign. I want to separate the values into multiple columns and remove the string separator (`@`).

NB: The values are usually text, but may be of variable length.

I have both Googled, and searched Stackoverflow numerous times for solutions, but most are not applicable as I have a variable string length and also variable value length :(

Thanks in advance!

Example:

```
Original column
--------------------------------
Value1@Value2@Value3@Value4@Value5
Value1@Value2@Value3
Value1@Value2@Value3@Value4@Value5@Value6`
```

What I want:

```
Column1    Column2     Column3   Column4      Column5   Column6
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Value1     Value2      Value3    Value4       Value5
Value1     Value2      Value3
Value1     Value2      Value3    Value4       Value5    Value6
```

Comment: Side note: it's a **column** (not a *coloumn*)

Answer (score 2):

What's your Teradata release?

TD14 supports STRTOK:

```
STRTOK(col,'@',1), STRTOK(col,'@',2), STRTOK(col,'@',3), etc.
```

Comment: TD14, sorry for not specifying.

STRTOK works, BUT unfortunately I think my string is too long, because I get the following error when I exceed 9 coloumns (I need more):

SELECT Failed. 9804:  Response Row size or Constant Row size overflow. 
Second I also experience another problem when I add other columns that are not part of the STRTOK expression. (Would be glad if you could explain whats wrong):
SELECT Failed. 6810:  The owner expression of the UDM invocation 'STRTOK' is not a UDT 

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Any alternative solutions? 

Regex..?

Comment: STRTOK results in a VARCHAR(8000) UNICODE, you can simply CAST it to a shorter string

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use the REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE function to split the source string into a table with each value as a row.